# How to change keyboard play button function?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, winamp

I'm using a Microsoft Wireless keyboard 3000 and want to change the play button.

When I press this button it opens Windows Media Player but I want it to open Winamp. The media buttons work for Winamp only when it is in focus.

I installed IntelliType but it didn't help (this is also the program that came with the keyboard).

When I tried to enable hot keys in Winamp (options) it threw me this error:

[image]

How can I get this working?

Comment: I think "pay button" should be "pLay button" :D

Comment: I found a solution, I removed the Microsoft software and defined the hot keys in winamp...
I till prefer to do it all with the Microsoft software but this is the best solution i found.

Answer (score 1):

Autohotkey may well be your answer!

`Media_Play_Pause:: Run P:\ATH\TO\WINAMP.exe`

Would open winamp when you hit play, you'd have to use the IfWinExist functions to actually make it play when winamp is already started. Good news, though, one of the examples in the help file is building a set of WinAmp hotkeys, so you'd have no trouble at all :)

Comment: this is nice but when i press the play button it always opens the winamp and only then it pause/play it...
Is there a way to do it with the original program of Microsoft?

Comment: It's been a long time since I've used WinAmp, so I've no real experience with it. Autohotkey can do it, but you'll need somebody with experience of WA (Or learn the scripting language yourself, it's really very simple!)

Comment: http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic8222.html may be of use to you, looks to be pretty comprahensive.

Comment: what player do u use? (maybe I'll like it more that winamp)

Comment: I use Foobar2000, it's a fairly minimalist but brilliant player. If you use winamp's library a lot you may miss some of the features, but fb2k plays music and does it well. It also has a fantastic array of command line switches, here you'd do: `Media_Play_Pause:: Run P:\ath\to\foobar2000.exe /play` and it'd start playing when you hit the button :)

Comment: I'm using the libraries of winamp so foobar is not for me.. :(

Answer (score 0):

A program like [Key Tweak](http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/) might be able do this, depending on the keyboard (and OS) and whether you want to get your hands a bit dirty with commands and parameters.

Otherwise [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) is made for this kind of thing.