# Keyboard mulfunction

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, freeze

I have a problem with the keyboard on my computer. When I click the shortcuts keyboard buttons my computer freezes (I can move the mouse but I can't make things work)
Its not a specific keyboard, it happens with all keyboards.

what could be the cause for it?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that some of what you did in [How to change keyboard play button function?](https://superuser.com/questions/61576/how-to-change-keyboard-play-button-function) caused the problem? If so can you remove and reinstall the latest version of the keyboard software after running system updates?

Comment: I'm talking about different computer.